# Zend_Db_Abstract subclass (Model)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a problem with my application's model. it should save a new user in a mysql database.

application/config/application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "pass"
resources.db.params.dbname = "cms"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

application/controllers/MemberController.php:

```
public function newAction()
{
    $frmNewMember = new Form_MemberRegisterationForm();
    $frmNewMember->setMethod('post');
    $frmNewMember->setAction('/member/new');
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        if ($frmNewMember->isValid($_POST))
        {
            $memberModel = new Model_Members();
            // process the data
            $result = true;
            $result = $memberModel->createMember(
                $frmNewMember->getValue('name'), 
                $frmNewMember->getValue('lastName'), 
                $frmNewMember->getValue('uid'), 
                $frmNewMember->getValue('email'), 
                $frmNewMember->getValue('password'));
            if ($result)
            {
                $this->_forward('confirm');
            }
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $frmNewMember;
}
```

application/models/Members.php:

```
public function createMember($name, $lastName, $uid, $email, $password)
{
    // Create row data
    $row = $this->createRow();
    $row->name = $name;
    $row->lastName = $lastName;
    $row->uid = $uid;
    $row->email = $email;
    $row->pasword = md5($password);
    // Save the row
    $row->save();
    $id = $this->_db->lastInsertId();
    return $id;
}
```

When I click on send button this error occures:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE' 
in /var/www/project/application/controllers/ErrorController.php on line 11
```

I know the problem is about `$row = $this->createRow();` code. because when I replace whole `createMember` method's body with `return $true` there is no error.

*UPDATE:*

this is my `_initAutoload()` in the Bootsreap.php. should I add something to configure database?

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    // Add autoloader empty namespace
    $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoLoader->registerNamespace('CMS_');
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(
        array ('basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH, 'namespace' => '', 
            'resourceTypes' => array (
                'form' => array ('path' => 'forms/', 
                    'namespace' => 'Form_' ), 
                'model' => array ('path' => 'models/', 
                    'namespace' => 'Model_' ) ) ));
    // Return it so that it can be stored by the bootstrap
    return $autoLoader;
}
```

*2nd UPDATE:*
The exception thrown is:

exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)' in /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:138 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #1 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(444): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #2 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(232): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `cms`....', Array) #3 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(156): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `cms`....') #4 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(727): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable('members', 'cms') #5 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(753): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupMetadata() #6 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(1297): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_getCols() #7 /var/www/project/application/models/Members.php(33): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->createRow(Array, NULL, true) #8 /var/www/project/application/controllers/MemberController.php(32): Model_Members->createMember('1', '1', '1', 'soroush.rabiei@...', NULL) #9 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(512): MemberController->newAction() #10 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(288): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('newAction') #11 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(945): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #12 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(77): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #13 /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Application.php(328): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() #14 /var/www/project/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run() #15 {main}

Comment: What class are you using in ErrorController on line 11? Is it `Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE`? The problem is in the ErrorController. Fix that and you will see the error the model is throwing.

Comment: Ok, I did so and now result is `An error occurred
Application error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is quite clear :

```
exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)' in /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:138
```

This means that your DB driver tries to connect to mysql via a socket located in /tmp/mysql.sock on your server, but does not find it.

You have 3 options :

- configure your mysql server (through my.cnf) to put it's socket in /tmp. This option should be used carefully as it has an impact on all applications using the same mysql instance
- find where mysql puts it's socket, and edit your php.ini to point to that socket. This option must be used carefully too, because it has an impact on every php application used on the server

Example : 
    ; under the [Pdo_mysql] section of the php.ini
    pdo_mysql.default_socket=/mysql.sock

- Configure your application to connect through a socket. That's a PDO option, and it should be passed to your Zend_Db_Adapter constructor, as described in the example #7 of [this page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html).

The option is named unix_socket and is described in the [PDO DSN](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) php.net doc page

Comment: I added `resources.db.params.unix_socket="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"
` to the application.ini. Thanks